# What is the purpose of integration services if its resources are not used in absence of db engine?

Tags: ssis

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/install-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver15#installing-a-dedicated-server-for-etl-processes

> If the ETL server doesn't have an instance of the Database Engine, you
> have to schedule or run packages from a server that does have an
> instance of the Database Engine. As a result, the packages aren't
> running on the ETL server, but instead on the server from which
> they're started. As a result, the resources of the dedicated ETL
> server aren't being used as intended.

For ssis we need integration services selected during install. Say server 1 has integration services installed and no db engines. Server 2 has db engine (and the ssis db)  and agent job on which ssis package is configured to run. As per quote above, it will run on server 2 resources. So what exactly is the purpose of integration services?

And what exactly decides where the ssis etl runs?

Comment: If you just use a different scheduler on the SSIS box (or run a remote process) it'll actually use the  SSIS server. If you really wanted to have split servers I would suggest just installing SQL Server (and the SSISDB) on the ETL Server. But I've never seen this split configuration

Comment: DTexec.exe and the corresponding libraries are installed where SSIS is installed.   You can manually run packages from command line from server 1 using dtexec, but SQL Server Agent's catalog integration only run packages locally.

Comment: Package will always run where the db engine is located. So what is the purpose of keeping integration services and db engine separate?